# Cut object in iOS using Camera

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, camera, cocoapods

I'm doing an iOS app, and one of the features and take a picture of an object.

For example take a picture of a shirt and he would be able to cut the shirt.

How do to cut this object, is there a pod or library could to facilitate this operation?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too broad a topic for a single SO question. There are some libraries available for object detection -- [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) being perhaps the most widely used. But that's far from a complete solution to your problem -- OpenCV provides a number of useful tools, but you'll still need to learn what they do and how to use them. For example, you can use OpenCV to do edge detection, which might be appropriate for letting the user pick distinct objects out of an image, and it also provides tools that could help you automatically find objects that have specific features, such as faces.